# Error LNK2001: Unresolved External Symbol with std::to_wstring() in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2022

I'm updating visual studio 2019 to 2022 for 200+ projects of our product and encountered a tricky issue after I updated VS to 2022:
For one project, there will be such link issue:

```
*error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) private: static void __cdecl **std::basic_string**<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::**_Start_element_lifetimes**(wchar_t * const,unsigned __int64)" (imp?_Start_element_lifetimes@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@CAXQEA_W_K@Z)*
```

The tricky thing is the link error only happened when I made Debug build, for release build it always pass.
And the link error only happened when I use the std function **std::to_wstring()**.
In my machine, I both installed VS 2019 and 2022.

I try to create a empty vs 2022 project, and use **std::to_wstring()** in the project, it has no problem.

Is there anyone also encountered such issue?
Thank you!

Comment: is all your code compiled with 2022? There's backwards compatibility for shared libraries but not always static libraries

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.